# SQL how to select data in this specific situation

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 tables with their columns.

```
'players': id

'items': player_id,item_id,quantity

'item_list': id,price
```

I want to select all items the player has in a list:

```
("select * from items where player_id=$player_id")
```

while to display the items data form 'items_list' table. The output should be like this

> Hi, I have id `$player_id`. Here are my items
>
> item_id1 price1 How many: $quantity1
>
> item_id2 price2 How many: $quanity2

and so on

how to do that? i dont want to query my base for every (`while $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)`). That would be too heavy. I want to do 1 or 2 queries (union? outer join? inner join? i dont rly know. I'm asking.) and they display the data. anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join with group by clause.

```
select i.item_id, il.price, i.quantity
from items i, items_list il
where i.player_id=$player_id
and i.item_id = il.item_id
group by i.item_id
```

Comment: i put items instead of i and item_list instead of il?

Comment: eeehh how i display the data? please help

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, I think you can do that with a JOIN:

```
SELECT il.id AS ItemID ,il.price AS ItemPrice,i.quantity AS ItemQtY
FROM items i
INNER JOIN item_list il ON i.item_id = il.id
WHERE player_id = $player_id
```

This gives you the price information from item_list table along with the quantity from items table.

Comment: and how to display them with 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
echo $row['table_name'];
what i put instead of 'table_name'?

Comment: I'm not very fluent in php, but i think it should be `echo $row['columnName']`. I edited my answer to put more meaningful aliases. use ItemId, ItemPrice and ItemQty

Comment: @user3033026. Were you able to make it work? I can't see a reason on why you would need a group by in this case. Any reason you forgot to mention?

Comment: i just want to make a game. mate can you tell me how i can display the column data of the 2 tables, if some columns in these tables have the same name?

Comment: Use different aliases like i did for the columns in my query: "AS something". And then you can refer to that specific column in php.

Comment: can you say an example? didnt get you. you say me to rename my columns?

Comment: ok. do you know how i can select every columns (*) in the table instead of writing il.id,il.price,il.name .... ??

Comment: SELECT * is a bad practice. I advise you not to do that. By selecting only the columns you want you increase the speed and among other advantages, if one day you remove a column from your table, you can look for it more easily.

Comment: i want to select all now. how to do it?

Comment: You can use the column names id, price and quantity.